# Select data within a date range using form

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I would like to search a mysql database for a list of products that have been inserted between a date range.
Say I have a table called product which has: id, name, brand, and datecreated, I can do this in mysql:

```
select id, name, brand, datecreated 
  from product 
 where datecreated between '2013-09-12' and '2013-10-10'
 order by datecreated desc;
```

This will obviously return the desired result either in Mysql or within php.

However I would like to define the date range in the select statement with a form which asks the user for the to and from dates.  Not sure what the method will be either ?

```
    <form action="?" method="">
        <div id="dates">
            <label for="searchdates">Enter your dates here:</label>
            <br>
            <label for="fromdate">From:<textarea id="fromdate" name="fromdate" rows="1" cols="5"></textarea></label>
            <lablel for="todate">To:<textarea id="todate" name="todate" rows="1" cols="5"></textarea></label>
        </div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Search"/></div>
    </form>
```

So what I am unsure of is how the user defined date range from the form can be added/inserted to the select statement to return the data within the defined date range?

Cheers
Volterony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact syntax depends on how you're interacting with your database (MySQLi, PDO, etc.).  You basically need to take the POSTed form values, do some straightforward validation to make sure that the user hasn't entered anything dangerous, then insert the values into the query:

```
$from = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['fromdate']);
$to = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['todate']);
$sql = "select id, name, brand, datecreated from product where datecreated between '$from' and 
'$to' order by datecreated desc";
```

The action on the form would be whichever page you place the above code in - it could be the same page as the form.  In that case, the action would be `<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>` and the method would be `POST`.

Comment: I appreciate your response to this question danmullen.  Now that it has been explained, I can see what is required so I'll give this a try.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The user-submitted values would come in as `$_POST['fromdate']` and `$_POST['todate']`, or `$_GET['fromdate']` and `_$GET['todate']`, depending on whether your form method above was `post` or `get` (I'd generally recommend `post` in case there is a specific reason for using `get`, like wanting to bookmark the page).

So your code to handle this could look something like this (assuming `$pdo` is your database PDO object):

```
$fromdate = new DateTime( $_POST['fromdate'] );
$todate   = new DateTime( $_POST['todate'] );

$query = <<<SQL
  SELECT id, name, brand, datecreated
    FROM product
   WHERE datecreated BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate
   ORDER BY datecreated desc
SQL;

$result = $pdo->prepare( $query );
$result->execute( array(
    ":fromdate" => $fromdate->format( "Y-m-d" ),
    ":todate"   => $todate->format( "Y-m-d" );
));

$rows = $result->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ):
```

`$rows` now contains an array of all of the rows of your table that match the specified criteria.

Comment: Nick, thanks for your response.  I am not using PDO for this particular situation, however your example will prove very useful when I use PDO in future.

Comment: In either case, you'll want to format the date properly before using it with your query. @danmullen's answer that you've accepted will only work if the user submits the date in the format "Y-m-d", and will break when they enter it in a more common format, like "n/d/Y".